# LINQ IEnumerable Where Not Finding Element

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of class items `List<MyClass>`

I have a seperate object that is of type MyClass

In my list I have an instance of this item but my where statement fails.

```
var home = Item.Find(23);
var item = allitems.Where(i => i == home);
```

item yields no results

`allitems.Contains(home)` also fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are they definately tghe same items? If you have this situation;

```
var item1 = new Place(23);
var item2 = new Place(23);
```

then `item1 != item2`. If the items are identified by some property, you could try

```
allitems.Where(i => i.Id == home.Id)
```

Comment: I've done it by ID thanks. Why is item1 considered different than item2 though?

Comment: Because they're different objects. Unless it's overloaded, "==" compares for identity rather than equality - you can have two laptops which are equal in every respect, but they're still distinct laptops for example.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding Equals() in "Item" should also work.

```
var home = Item.Find(23);
var item = allitems.Where(i => i.Equals(home));
```